# What is this comma notation for the definition of position vectors? (basis vectors)

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems

In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position_(vector)#Three_dimensions), this formula is used to show the definition of position vectors in all three coordinate systems: [position vectors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKEyJ.png). In spherical coordinates, the position vector is defined as:

$\vec{r}(r,\theta,\phi)=r(t)\hat{e}_r(\theta(t),\phi(t))$

But I don't understand what the comma means. $\hat{e}_r$ is the radial unit vector.

Comment: It means $\hat{e}_r$ is a function depending of two variables: $\theta$ and $\phi$, which in turn depend on $t$.

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz: That's an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is functional notation. It means that $\hat{e}_{r}$ is a function depending on two variables: $\theta$ and $\phi$, which in turn depend on $t$.

That is because the basis vector $\hat{e}_{r}$ always points outwards from the origin, so when you change $\theta$ or $\phi$ the vector cannot stay constant.

Comment: Wow, yikes, I can't believe I didn't realize it was function notation... Thanks!